# how to run a coffee-script project in cloud 9

Tags: coffeescript, cloud9-ide

I've been contemplating moving my project over to cloud 9 IDE but have been having trouble running coffee script in the project.  I copied over all my js and coffee files but can't seem to get a run configuration working using the coffee files.  I tried compiling the coffee files in the console command line as well as creating a run configuration that calls the app.coffee directly but no luck.

What is the coffee script support on cloud 9 and how does it work.  Does it compile the coffee script to js automatically?  How do I need to configure my run settings in cloud 9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working... your results may vary, but this is what I did...

Assuming you have your app which is called `app.coffee`, I created a file called `runner.js` with the following code:

```
require("coffee-script");
require("./app");
```

From the Cloud9 IDE, I just tell it to run the `runner.js` file and it seems to work.

I also wasn't able to use my global npm-installed packages... not sure why, but I am guessing it is just a pathing issue.  Anyways, I just installed my packages into my project directory:

```
npm install coffee-script
```

I was also using `express` and `restler` in my project so I did the same thing in the project.  It worked beautiffuly :)

Comment: sweet.  what about compiling dependent include files.  I like to have a separate models.coffee, controllers.coffee, etc...  coffee -c ./ doesn't seem to work in the console..

Comment: As long as the "coffee-script" module is required, requirements of other files should work without translating to javascript.  For instance, I have a `coffee.config` module in the same folder.  I can require it: `config = require './config'` and it evaluates without the need to translate to JS.  You should be able to `controllers = require ./controllers`.  That isn't working for you?

Comment: thanks for the tip... trying it out and unfortunately something seems to be going on in the rendering.  It definitely looks at the coffee file now but seems to be blank redering.  I'll dig into it a bit more and see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

There is an entry on the Cloud9 support page on running node.js applications written in CoffeeScript: [Create a CoffeeScript node.js project](http://cloud9ide.zendesk.com/entries/20559696-create-a-coffeescript-node-js-project). Note that you can only debug the javascript files.